# Can not Resolve React Native Camera MLKit Dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

My app builds fine on Android Studio, it runs fine with `react-native run-android` but when I try to generate the `.apk` it fails with `./gradlew assembleRelease` command. I get the following error.

## Error Message

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':react-native-camera:compileMlkitReleaseAidl'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':react-native-camera:mlkitReleaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:12.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-camera
   > Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:12.0.1.
     Required by:
         project :react-native-camera
```

### package.json

```
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.10",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.7.1",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.28.1",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.2.3",
```

### gradle properties

```
classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.0') // FROM android/gradle.build
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip // FROM gradle-wrapper.properties
```

I have followed the installation instructions [here](https://react-native-community.github.io/react-native-camera/docs/installation#android) and followed GitHub links [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/2150#issuecomment-476011915) and [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-camera/issues/2063).

All have the same solution which I have completed, i.e. adding;

### android/app/build.gradle

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general'
  }
}
```

### Note

The issue is because android is looking for `mlkit` dependencies even when I have not opted for them. I think this is happening because I use `react-native-image-picker` and `react-native-qrcode-scanner` one of these packages is looking mlkit dependencies. But I don't know how to debug and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure that in the     android/app/build.gradle you added this

```
missingDimensionStrategy 'react-native-camera', 'general' in *defaultConfig*
```

Then check your internet connectivity is good while building. 
If it doesn't work, use 
    npm run release